# Sort list of objects by a number of attributes using a generator

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

I've got a list of objects which will number somewhere between the thousands & tens of thousands. These objects could be thought of as people which I'm looking to rank based on a score they have.

So first of all they're split into groups by age, then gender etc. At each point a ranking is provided corresponding to that age/gender category. The fields on the objects are `age_group` and `gender`. So you'd first collect everybody that's got the `30-39` age group, then all the men (`M`) and all women (`W`) from that age group.

Creating a new list at each of these points is very memory intensive so I'm attempting to use a generator & [itertools](/questions/tagged/itertools) to group using the original list. So I've got a function to do that;

```
def group_standings(_standings, field):
    """ sort list of standings by a given field """
    getter = operator.attrgetter(field)
    for k, g in itertools.groupby(_standings, getter):
        yield list(g)


def calculate_positions(standings):
    """
    sort standings by age_group then gender & set position based on point value 
    """
    for age_group in group_standings(standings, 'age_group'):

        for gender_group in group_standings(age_group, 'gender'):

            set_positions(
                standings=gender_group,
                point_field='points',
                position_field='position',
            )
```

For `set_positions` to function correctly it needs the whole group so that it can sort by the `point_field` value then set the `position_field` value.

Debugging the generator, `groupby` isn't collecting all objects matching the key as I'd expected. The output is something like;

```
DEBUG generating k 30-39
DEBUG generating g [<Standing object at 0x7fc86fedbe10>, <Standing object at 0x7fc86fedbe50>, <Standing object at 0x7fc86fedbe90>]

DEBUG generating k 20-29
DEBUG generating g [<Standing object at 0x7fc86fedbed0>]

DEBUG generating k 30-39
DEBUG generating g [<Standing object at 0x7fc86fedbf10>]

DEBUG generating k 20-29
DEBUG generating g [<Standing object at 0x7fc86fedbf50>, <Standing object at 0x7fc86fedbf90>, <Standing object at 0x7fc86fedbfd0>, <Standing object at 0x7fc856ecc050>, <Standing object at 0x7fc856ecc090>, <Standing object at 0x7fc856ecc0d0>, <Standing object at 0x7fc856ecc110>, <Standing object at 0x7fc856ecc150>, <Standing object at 0x7fc856ecc190>, <Standing object at 0x7fc856ecc1d0>]
```

To confirm, for `set_positions` to function, the list provided by the generator would need to contain all objects in the `20-29` age group, but as above, objects from that group are being found on multiple iterations of the list.

Comment: Include *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because groupby function assumes that the input iterable is already sorted by key (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)). It's made for performance but is confusing. 
Also, I wouldn't cast `g` to a list in `group_standings` function but applied it only when you pass `gender_group` to `set_positions`.

Comment: Thank you, that's obvious looking at it now, but completely missed that in the docs when we implemented this yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

#### `groupby` works on adjacent elements

As per [@MikhailBerlinkov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53352520/edit), `groupby` aggregates **consecutive items only** which are the same, optionally using a `key` argument for comparison.

It may help to see an example:

```
from itertools import groupby

L = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]

res = [list(j) for _, j in groupby(L)]

[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [1, 1]]
```

As you can see, the groups of `1` values are split into *two* separate lists.

#### Sort before grouping

Instead, you can sort your list of objects before grouping. For a large list of objects, say of length *n*, this takes O(*n* log *n*) time. Here's an example (using same `L` as before):

```
L_sorted = sorted(L)

res = [list(j) for i, j in groupby(L_sorted)]

[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```